# PyQt: QDateComboBox setDate using string?

Tags: python, string, combobox, pyqt, date-formatting

How can I set the date of a QDateComboBox using a string that some times can also be empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about [QDateEdit](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdateedit.html), you will need to create a [QDate](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdate.html) object from the string so that it can be passed to the [setDate](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdatetimeedit.html#date-prop) function.

The QDate class has a static [fromString](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdate.html#fromString) function that can create a QDate from a string, but you will have to know the *format* of the date in the string for it to work properly.

By default, `QDate.fromString` assumes dates will be in the following format:

```
ddd MMM d yyyy (ShortDayName ShortMonthName ShortDayNumber LongYearNumber)
e.g. Thu Dec 6 2012
```

However, you can specify a format as the second argument to `fromString` by passing either a standard [DateFormat](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#DateFormat-enum), or a custom [format string](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdate.html#fromString-2).

If QDate can't parse the date-string, an invalid QDate object will be returned (you can check this with `date.isValid()`).

An empty string will produce an invalid date object, but if you pass one to `QDateEdit.setDate`, it will be ignored (i.e. the date won't change).

Comment: If the date format can vary a bit, check out the [`dateutil` module](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-c0e81a473b647dfa787dc11e8c69557ec2c3ecd2) included in the standard library. It had dateutil.parser.parse() which can try to figure it out for you and return a `datetime`

Comment: @jdi. Good point, but I don't think `dateutil` is in the python standard library.

Comment: What do I use for DayNumber/MonthNumber/Year?

Comment: Found it: setDate(QDate.fromString(text, "dd/MM/yyyy"))

Answer (score 0):

I think you're talking about `QDateEdit` which can be set using `setDate(QDate)`. To create a `QDate` from a string, use `QDate.fromString`. See [QT 3 QDateTime API](http://doc.qt.digia.com/3.3/qdatetime.html) or [QT 4 QDateTime API](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qdatetime.html&ei=p-LAUOPwDsSLiALLoYCYAw&usg=AFQjCNG26vUJEW7thHkO_5bMk7XtTIfDww)